# Can $R=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0 \}$ be a set of infinite isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to - \infty}f(x) = \infty$. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$. Consider $R$ the set of the $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 0$. Can $R$ be a set of infinite isolated points?

My guess is it cannot be, but I don't see how to rigorously prove it

Comment: Let each point be labelled $(x_{a})_{a \in A}$. I would advise using the distance function and the fact that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{inf}_{i\neq j}(dist(x_{i},x_{j})) \geq \frac{1}{n}$. You still need somekind of 'control', since the infimum of the distance between an infinite number of isolated points is probably zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $f$ has a limit of $\infty$ at $\pm\infty$, then $f$ cannot vanish outside some finite interval $[a,b]$. If $f$ has an infinite number of distinct zeros $\{ z_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $[a,b]$, then, by the Heine-Borel Theorem, there has to be a subsequence $\{ z_{n_{k}} \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to be a point  $z_{\infty} \in [a,b]$. By continuity of $f$, one must have $f(z_{\infty})=0$, which means that $z_{\infty}$ is not an isolated root.

Comment: I hope you mean Bolzano-Weierstrass and not Heine-Borel.

Answer (score 4):

As $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to - \infty}f(x) = \infty$ there must be some $k \in \mathbb{R_+}$, such that $f(x)>1$ for $x \notin [-k,k$]. Thus we have $R \subset [-k,k]$. But how many isolated points can that set contain?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think we must look for the continuity to affirm that it must be finite, dont we?

Comment: @Giiovanna indeed, the answer of T.A.E. should give you the idea on how to show finiteness.